# Se puede generar este update en SQL server

Tags: sql-server, trigger, update

Buenas tardes y gracias por su tiempo. Tengo que crear un update desde un trigger y el valor del campo a actualizar es el resultado de una subconsulta, la subconsulta funciona lo que no se es si puede usarse en un update y menos desde un trigger (que la verdad no soy muy devoto). Gracias de nuevo por su tiempo y agradezco opiniones.

`````
CREATE TRIGGER TR_AmmountPremium
ON insudb.Commis_pr -- cuando se inserta en commis_pr actualizo en premmiun
FOR
INSERT
AS

DECLARE @sErrorMessage VARCHAR(300)--- variable en caso de error. 


    UPDATE insudb.Premium set Premium.nComamou = cp.nAmount WHERE
    (
        SELECT pr.nReceipt, pr.nComamou, cp.nAmount
        FROM insudb.Premium pr (NOLOCK)
        INNER JOIN INSERTED I -- registro insertado en insudb.Commiss_pr -- 
        ON I.nReceipt = pr.nReceipt
        AND I.nDigit = 0 AND I.nPaynumbe = 0
        OUTER APPLY (SELECT SUM(nAmount) nAmount
        FROM insudb.Commiss_pr cp (NOLOCK)
        WHERE cp.nReceipt = I.nReceipt
        AND cp.nDigit = 0 AND I.nPaynumbe = 0) AS cp
        WHERE ISNULL(pr.nComamou,0) = 0.00
        AND cp.nAmount <> 0.00 -- el valor de commis_pr
    )
    
    IF(@@ERROR > 0)
    
    
        set @sErrorMessage='Error, no se pudo actualizar el monto en Premmim.nAmount, por favor avise a su administrador'
        ROLLBACK TRANSACTION
        RAISERROR(@sErrorMessage,1,16)
    
        ````
`````

Comment: Muchas gracias. Mas que error quería saber si la sintaxis del update es correcta. Tengo dudas en si es where o FROM y no me acceden ambiente para asociar el trigger. Perdón por sacarles sus tiempo con esto.

Comment: Sos un grande! el from (subconsulta).  Mil gracias!